# Imagick: долгая обработка gif

Tags: imagick, php

Простейшая команда из примеров на сайте, обработка гиф файла, его ресайз.

```
$gif = new Imagick('test.gif');

foreach ($gif as $frame) {
    $frame->thumbnailImage(50, 50);
    $frame->setImagePage(50, 50, 0, 0);     
}

$gif->writeImages("example_small.gif", true);
```

Но почему то она очень долго обрабатывается, слетает таймаут. Весит гиф файл 135кб.

Насчет `imagick`:

`imagick module version     3.0.0RC1`

Есть поддержка `GIF`, `GIF87`

Так же, проверял на `png` картинке - его она обрабатывает с приемлемой скоростью.

Comment: А сколько там фреймов? И что за png?

Comment: 7 фреймов. ПНГ так же обычный, 15 Кб.

Comment: Хм.. Может недостаточно ресурсов сервера? Или 400мб должно хватить?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php

под настрой imagemagick. Для php OpenMP лучше отключить.

convert -debug много чего расскажет..

и поставь ImageMagick > 6.8.6-9 beta.. там решена какая-то проблема с выделением ресурсов и как результат, стало в десяток раз быстрее